# Java 8 - Process list of elements in CompleteableFuture's thenCompose method

Tags: java, asynchronous, lambda, java-8, completable-future

Please find below a made-up example of my actual code. This example has been oversimplified to explain what I am trying to achieve.

```
public class TestClass {

ForkJoinPool forkJoinPool = new ForkJoinPool(3);

@Test 
public void testSample(){
    List<String> testStrings = Arrays.asList("Hello", "World", "Cobra", "Eagle", "Sam");

    //This doesn't compile
    List<CompletableFuture<Double>> result =
            testStrings.stream().map(each -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> getIndividualCharacters(each), forkJoinPool)
                    .thenComposeAsync(listOfChars -> listOfChars.stream()
                            .map(character -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> getDoubleString(character)))
                            .collect(Collectors.toList())));

}

public List<String> getIndividualCharacters(String name){
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i =0; i < name.length(); i++){
        result.add(Character.toString(name.charAt(i)));
    }
    return result;
}

public Double getDoubleString(String singleCharacter){
    return Math.random();
}
```

}

My `getIndividualCharacters` method returns a list of results (Asynchronously). I use the individual result and process it further to return another result (Asynchronously).
What I want as the end result is a `List<Completeable<final result>>` in this case `List<Completeable<Double>>` which I can use inside
`CompleteablFuture.allOf`

I want to use chaining of CompleteableFuture if possible. I haven't managed to find a way to do it nor any examples mention it.
Any help or pointers on how to achieve this will be really helpful.

PS: I have managed to solve the problem using two separate CompleteableFuture streams, however, I want to use chaining `thenCompose`

```
List<String> testStrings = Arrays.asList("Hello", "World", "Cobra", "Eagle", "Sam");
        List<CompletableFuture<List<String>>> firstResult = testStrings.stream()
                .map(each -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> getIndividualCharacters(each), forkJoinPool))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        CompletableFuture.allOf(firstResult.toArray(new CompletableFuture[firstResult.size()])).join();
        List<CompletableFuture<Double>> secondResult = firstResult.stream()
                .flatMap(res -> res.join().stream())
                .map(ea -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> getDoubleString(ea), forkJoinPool))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        List<Double> finalResult = secondResult.stream().map(res-> res.join()).collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println("finalResult " + finalResult);
```

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

I guess something like this?

```
List<CompletableFuture<Double>> result =
  testStrings.stream()
             .map(x -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> getIndividualCharacters(x)))
             .map(x -> x.thenApplyAsync(y -> y.stream().map(z -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> getDoubleString(z)))))
             .flatMap(CompletableFuture::join)
             .collect(toList());
```

Just notice that this will block because of `join`.

Comment: Thanks for your response Eugene. Appreciate it. As you rightly pointed out yourself, this particular implementation will block as you have added ```join``` so basically rendering ```CompletableFuture``` useless as it won't run in parallel.
I obviously do not want to lose the benefit of multi-threading

Comment: @LearnToLive if you want a result that is _not_ `CompletableFuture<XXX>`, you will need to block somewhere in your chain to get that `XXX`, there is simply no way around it.

Comment: Thanks @Eugene. I was checking if I can do this in one go and not have to do a join in an intermediate step. But looks like it isn't possible.

Answer (score 0):

I'll add another answer, may be this can be of a solution to you. You could delay the execution of `join` from the previous answer only until you would need it. For example via:

```
 Stream<CompletableFuture<Double>> result = 
 testStrings.stream()
            .map(each -> supplyAsync(() -> getIndividualCharacters(each)))
            .map(x -> x.thenCompose(y -> supplyAsync(() -> y.stream().map(z -> supplyAsync(() -> getDoubleString(z))))))
            .flatMap(x -> Stream.of(x).map(CompletableFuture::join))
            .flatMap(Function.identity());
```

But this changes the result to a `Stream`, at the same time - the stream is only evaluated when a terminal operation is called.